# Understanding when to use let and <-

Tags: haskell

I have been playing around with Haskell for a bit now but I have not fully grasped how to use third party functions that run inside a Monad. Every time I go back to reading articles about Monads, etc. I get a good understanding but when it comes to applying them to real-world code, I cannot figure why a piece of code does not work. I resort to trial and error and usually get it to compile but I feel I should be able to use them properly the first time without trying to go through my heuristic of changes (try `let, <-, liftM,` etc.)

So I would like to ask a few questions based on this simple function, which admittedly does a lot of interesting things.

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.HandsomeSoup
import Data.String.Utils

function h = do
    let url  = myUrlBuilder h
        doc  = fromUrl url
        res  = runX $ doc >>> css "strong" /> getText 
        --nres = liftM rmSpaceAndBang (res) 
    res

rmSpaceAndBang ps =  map (\x-> replace "!" "" (strip x))  ps
```

The above code compiles. I have purposefully left out the type declarations as what I thought it should be doesn't compile. So here are my questions.

**Why can I not do `res  <- runX ...` and return `res` that way?**

Why should `res` be inside a let statement and not be bound the result of action? As I understand it, `do x <- a1; a2` is equivalent to `a1 >>= \x -> a2`. How is that different when you `let x = a1`?

When I used `<-` I got the following error and if not for my trial and error approach I would not have been able to figure out that I need to use `let` here.

```
Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
Expected type: IO String
  Actual type: [String]
```

While I focused on `res` above, my lack of understanding applies to other `let` statements in the function as well.

**How do I find the return type of `res`?**

I couldn't figure out a way to search hackage for `getText` (hxt seems too big to look through module by module. Probably will try Google site search next time). In the end, I ended up typing up some parts of the code in GHCi and did `:t res`. It told me it is `[String]`. Is there a better way to do this?

Since res is of type `[String]` I thought I will put `[String]` as the return type for my function. But GHC says it should be `IO [String]` (compiles). Why did `:t` give me the wrong information first?

**When functions return `IO String`, what's the best way to use pure functions on them?**

Now that I am stuck inside `IO [String]` I need to use to lift everywhere I do string operations. Is there a better way to do this?

Hopefully I will learn enough from this that I will be able to use right syntax without resorting to blindly trying a few combinations.

**Update:**

The key piece I was missing was the fact `res` is not a value but rather an action. So I have 2 choices:  one is is my above code with `let res =` but call it at the end and the other is to do `res <-` but then do `return (res)`.

The advantage of using `res <-` is that I can get rid of the `liftM` as `res` is now `[String]` (see @duplode's answer below).

Thanks!

Comment: To search for a specific function in Hackage, try using Hayoo: http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html It supports searching by signature as well.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielDíazCarrete, when I do `hxt getText` in Hayoo found the function right away! The return type of getText is `a XmlTree String`. I see `runX` has this type `IOSArrow XmlTree c -> IO [c]`. I understand how I get an IO [String] now.

Comment: `let x = a1 ...` is pretty much like `(\x -> ...) a1`, as opposed to what `<-` gets turned into.

Comment: You can even do it without `res`, just put `runX $ doc >>> css "strong" /> getText` after the let bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fast answer, let doesn't run anything, it's just makes the lhs as a synonym for rhs.

You actually need a monadic function inside the do for computation be executed.

```
  main = do 
     let func = print "I need to be called"
     print "I don't need to be called"
     func
```

outputs:

```
  "I don't need to be called"
  "I need to be called"
```

So `res` in your code is not a value, it's a monadic action/function.

Remember that `<-` is tied to `>>=`, and requires a `a -> m b` on the rhs.

let has no requirements.

Comment: Thank you! `res` is not a value but an action is the clue I was missing. I will update my post with my new functions so others like me can benefit.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `res` is an `IO [String]`. I do not doubt that you got `[String]` through GHCi at first, but I believe you tested it with

```
>>> res <- runX $ doc >>> css "strong" /> getText
>>> :t res
res :: [String]
```

Which is not equivalent to your code. The difference is that `let` just binds your `IO [String]` action without running it, while `<-` in a `do` block runs the action and binds the *result*, in this case a `[String]`.

> Now that I am stuck inside IO [String] I need to use to lift
>   everywhere I do string operations. Is there a better way to do this?

Within a do block, sometimes it is more convenient to write:

```
res <- runX $ doc >>> css "strong" /> getText
return $ rmSpaceAndBang res
```

Which is strictly equivalent to using `liftM` (or `fmap`):

```
liftM rmSpaceAndBang $ doc >>> css "strong" /> getText
```

Comment: Thank you and up voted. I accepted @MdxBhmt's answer but you also answered my questions. I guess that's the problem with asking multiple questions in one thread. You are correct about what I did in GHCi and now I understand why I got different results.